# How to add Edgecolor for the hist plot (sons)

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, data-visualization, seaborn

I am using the Iris data for pairplot. But the hist plot looks really ugly (e.g. the Top left pic), how can I add the edge color (white) to make it cleaner?

The code I used was like this:

```
sns.pairplot(df, hue="Species", size=3, plot_kws={'edgecolor':'white'})
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `diag_kws` (diagonal is according to histograms) argument of `pairplot` and set in it desired `edgecolor`:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

df = sns.load_dataset("iris")
sns.pairplot(df, hue="species", size=3, diag_kws={'edgecolor':'w'})
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It's working now. And I just realised that this **diag_kws** is only for the diagonal plots, for the others I can use this:

```sns.pairplot(df, hue="Species", size=3, diag_kws={'edgecolor':'w'}, plot_kws=dict(s=50, edgecolor="w", linewidth=0.5))```